# IIS Configuration auto redirect for non-working alias to application

Tags: iis

On following the instructions to deploy an asp.net core application it looks like the following:

```
 - Server
    - Application Pools
    - Sites
       - Default Web Site
          + aspnet_client
          + c_myapplication
          + ig_common
```

The URL `http://localhost/c_myapplication/` works correctly; however the there is also a non-working alias `http://localhost/c_myapplication` (it loads the root page with the wrong base so nothing else works).

How do I suppress the non-working alias or forward it to the correct alias?

OS is Windows 11; doesn't seem to be a specific tag for my IIS version.